# Dynamic styling not working in Angular2

Tags: css, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-template

Following is my working code, which is not giving any error in console and printing the array items and test heading as expected. BUT somehow dynamic background styling in not working, Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
        <div class="one" *ngFor="let item of colArr" style="background: {{item}};">{{item}}</div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        .one {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    `]
})

export class HomeComponent {
    public name = 'test';
    public colArr = ['#111111', '#222222', '#333333', '#444444', '#555555', '#666666', '#777777', '#888888', '#999999'];
}
```

Following is the output I am getting  -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct binding to `style` is discouraged (doesn't work well on all browsers). Use instead

```
<div class="one" *ngFor="let item of colArr" [ngStyle]="{background: item}">{{item}}</div>
```

or

```
<div class="one" *ngFor="let item of colArr" [style.background]="item">{{item}}</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but your first solution is not working `[ngStyle]="{background: item;"` though second works fine +1

Comment: I missed a `}` in the first solution.

Comment: No it should be like this - `[ngStyle]="{background: item}"` otherwise it won't compile and give error due to `;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! One week of vacation and half the stuff already forgotten ;-)